# peculiarity between c ++ headers

Tags: c++

What is the difference between ( something.h, Csomething, and something )?

I have searched the Internet but I can not understand, which are libraries, which headers, and which are directives of the preprocessor ?.

I come from python and always to call a method or class of a module, the syntax is used:

```
name_modulo.class () or name_modulo.method ()
```

In c ++ it is not necessary to call the name of the module (directive, or header, I don't really know), only the class or method that is needed will be called directly.

Why is this happening?

Comment: These are good questions, but they're also something that can be answered by any good C++ introduction and reference. Learning C++ requires [good resources](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), as picking it up piecemeal will lead to an inadequate and incomplete understanding.

Comment: Mostly naming convention. The c-prefixed header files are the c++ version of the old C library headers plus whatever C++-isms have been added. stdio.h in C is cstdio in C++. tadman just made the rest of this comment obsolete.

Comment: It would help if you could show us some actual C++ code, not an approximation of something you think you saw.

Comment: and the something alone?

Comment: I think there are at least three distinct questions in the post. Maybe try to focus on one of them first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In C/C++, a "[compilation unit](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_015.HTM)" may contain C source code (.c file), C++ source (.cpp file) or declarations to be incorporated at compile time (.h "header" file).

The equivalent in Python would be  a "[module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)" (.py file).

To elaborate:

> https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_015.HTM
>
> A compilation unit is C source code that is compiled and treated as
>   one logical unit. The compilation unit is usually one or more entire
>   files, but can also be a selected portion of a file if, for example,
>   the #ifdef preprocessor directive is used to select specific code
>   sections. Declarations and definitions within a compilation unit
>   determine the scope of functions and data objects.
>
> Files included by using the #include preprocessor directive become
>   part of the compilation unit. Source lines skipped because of the
>   conditional inclusion preprocessor directives are not included in the
>   compilation unit.
>
> Compilation units are important in determining the scope of
>   identifiers, and in determining the linkage of identifiers to other
>   internal and external identifiers. Section 2.3 discusses scope.
>   Section 2.8 discusses linkage.
>
> A compilation unit can refer to data or functions in other compilation
>   units in the following ways:
>
> A function in one compilation unit can call a function in a different
>   compilation unit. Data objects can be assigned external linkage so
>   that other compilation units have access to them (see Section 2.8).
>   Programs composed of more than one compilation unit can be separately
>   compiled, and later linked to produce the executable program. A legal
>   C compilation unit consists of at least one external declaration, as
>   defined in Section 4.3.

Comment: Translation units work nothing like modules in Python. If at all, I would say namespaces (but separated between files by name) come closer to Python modules.